# How to Link to category titles if it is in the single post content?

Tags: php, categories

My English is not good. sorry.

I want to link to titles of child-categories that are in the single post content. (Wordpress)

Example:

My Categories:

> Aplle , Asia , Europ , North america , ...

My Post Content:

> An [apple](https://example.com/apple) is a sweet, edible fruit produced by an [apple](https://example.com/apple) tree (Malus domestica). [Apple](https://example.com/apple) trees are cultivated worldwide and are the most widely grown species in the genus Malus. The tree originated in Central [Asia](https://example.com/asia), where its wild ancestor, Malus sieversii, is still found today. Apples have been grown for thousands of years in [Asia](https://example.com/asia) and [Europe](https://example.com/europ) and were brought to [North America](https://example.com/north-america) by European colonists. Apples have religious and mythological significance in many cultures, including Norse, Greek and European Christian tradition.

and, My troubled PHP script for automatic create Link to category titles if it is in the single post content:

```
<?php
   $term_id = 1209;
   $taxonomy_name = 'category';
   $termchildren = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy_name );
   foreach ( $termchildren as $child ) {
      $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name );
      $mycatone = "'" . $term->name . "',";
      $mycattwo = '"' . "<a href='This-Category-URL-LINK'>" . $termd->name . "</a>" . '",';
   }
   function link_words($content){
      $words = array( $mycatone );
      $links = array( $mycattwo );
      $content = str_replace($words , $links ,$content);
      return $content;
   }
   add_filter('the_content', 'link_words');
?>

<?php the_content() ?>
```

> UPDATE:

This code is work for last child-category and dont work for all child-categories of cat-id=1209:

```
<?php
function link_words($content){
    $term_id = 1209;
    $taxonomy_name = 'category';
    $termchildren = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy_name );
      foreach ( $termchildren as $child ) {
    $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name );
    $termlink = get_term_link( $child, $taxonomy_name );
    $mycatname = "$term->name";
    $mycatlink = "<a href=$termlink> $term->name </a>";
      $content = str_replace(array($mycatname), array($mycatlink) ,$content);
      return $content;}
   }
   add_filter('the_content', 'link_words');
?>
<?php the_content() ?>
```

Comment: At first glance you're only searching for quoted values followed by a comma i.e. `'Apple',` and not just `Apple`, and your search is case sensitive (I think?) i.e. won't match `'apple',` but otherwise it looks OK. What's the problem - you're not getting the substitutions you're expecting?

Comment: thanks. yes i am not getting the substitutions expecting. I do not know what to do. and my english is not good.

Comment: I think my problem is here: function in foreach or foreach in function.

Comment: Actually you can pass arrays to str_replace as you’re doing to do multiple substitutions, so you don’t necessarily need a for loop in link_words. But if you want to do more complicated word matching, e.g. whole words case insensitively without quotes and a trailing comma, then you might need a loop and something more complicated than str_replace.

Comment: yes, i am update this code. and my php problem is not working for all categories in array.

Comment: fixed this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43929928/wordpress-replace-tag-words-in-content-with-links